# php mail | add multiple recipients

Tags: php, email

I have been trying to modify this PHP code (the working one) to send email to multiple recipients:

```
if(!isset($hasError)) {

        $emailTo = $contact_email;
        $subject = $subject;    
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nMessage: $comments";
        $headers = 'From <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

        wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

        $emailSent = true;

}
```

My solution:

```
if(!isset($hasError)) {

        $emailTo = $contact_email;
        $subject = $subject;    
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nMessage: $comments";
        $headers = 'From <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;
        $headers .= 'BCC hello@mymail.com'. . "\r\n";

        //wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
        wp_mail(null, $subject, $body, $headers);

        $emailSent = true;

}
```

My solution doesn't work. I have tried multiple scenarios but i'm still stuck. How do I add multiple recipients?

Comment: I'm working on a classified website, where users are able to publish whatever they want to sell or advertise from the front end. At the end of each published post, a client can get intouch with the seller by filling in  a contact form. By default, the email goes to the publisher. The function $contact_email , is the publishers email address. However, I would like to add additional recipients. This is a wordpress website.

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers .= 'BCC hello@mymail.com'."\r\n";
```

Ther was an extra point in the bcc row.